# Ember.js: programmatically load hasmany relationship

Tags: ember.js

Disclamer: I started using Ember.js few days ago

Suppose having these 2 models:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    answers: DS.hasMany('answer', {async: true})
});

App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
    question: DS.belongsTo('question'),
    text: DS.attr('string')
});
```

For some reasons I got this JSON (without "answers" list)

```
{
    ...
    "questions": [
        {"id": 1, "text": "Foo?"}, ...
    ]
}
```

In the template I want to load and show answers only if explicitly needed

```
{{#each questions itemController="question"}}
    <div class="answer-wrapper">
        {{text}}
        <button {{action "loadAnswers"}}>Load answers</button>
        <ul>
            {{#each answers}}
                <li>{{text}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

How can I do this in the controller's loadAnswer action?

```
App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    ...

    actions: {
        loadAnswers: function() {
            // programatically load answers
        }
    }
});
```

Workaround: I can do this changing the attribute in the template

```
{{#each loadedAnswers}}
    <li>{{text}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

and defining correctly the action

```
App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    ...

    actions: {
        loadAnswers: function() {
            // or loaded with ajax...
            this.set("loadedAnswers", [
                {id: 1, text: "foo"},
                {id: 2, text: "bar"}
            ]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap that portion of the template with an if statement.  The async relationship won't be fetched unless it's requested.

#### Controller

```
App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  showAnswers: false,
    ...

    actions: {
        loadAnswers: function() {
          this.set('showAnswers', true);
        }
    }
});
```

#### Template

```
{{#if showAnswers}}
   <ul>
       {{#each answers}}
           <li>{{text}}</li>
       {{/each}}
   </ul>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: The problem is that `answer` is empty at the beginning. I want to load the list only when I click on button "Show answers". Trying to set `answers` in `loadAnswers` Ember complains: 'Cannot set read-only property "answers" on object'

Comment: You probably want to avoid using a relationship on ember data then, just comment that out and manually set a property on the model.  With the relationship there, Ember Data will think you want to interact with it, though you actually don't.